# How to read Pebble watch application logs from Android device?

Tags: pebble-watch

I am trying to troubleshoot a watchface that has trouble interfacing with the configuration screen. Everything seems to work fine on an iOS device (which includes my phone) but there is a consistent and faulty behavior on Android.

My app writes some status data to the application log, and a couple of Android users have sent me their logs (via Pebble app on phone -> Support -> "Send crash logs to Pebble"). Now, the Pebble app on iOS sends the log files as plain text, but the Android app does not. I'm looking at files called pebble.log that are in some non-ascii format.

Does anyone know how to read pebble.log that originates from an Android device? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pebble.log attachment is a gzipped file - on my email system (gmail) the attachment is shown as `pebble.log.gz`.

My Mac uncompresses the file automatically if you double-click it, creating a folder with all the (text) log files.

On Windows I suggest downloading the attachment, and ensuring that it has the correct `.gz` extension, and then using a tool such [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the contained files.

Comment: Thanks! The file did not uncompress properly via the gzip utility on my Ubuntu workstation (hence the original question), but on my Mac laptop, it did.

Comment: Glad it worked out - I didn't figure on Ubuntu in my answer!